# Detect actual computer tilt

Tags: javascript, css, tilt

Any idea how this is done? https://dl.dropbox.com/u/45572383/23122012025.m4v

I was not aware you can detect physical computer screen tilt on other than handhelds. Does this have to do with me being on a Mac? Or will this work on any computer regardless?

Comment: Most definitely not "any computer", I can't see why I would tilt my PC ;-)

Comment: @Kos just nitpicking, but I found out that my laptop has an accelerometer when I accidentally dropped it and the system stopped touching the hard drive so that the disk wouldn't be damaged in the fall. It worked!

Comment: Nice! I wonder if tower PCs also have that. Mine fell (and flew) at least once :-)

Answer (score 5):

There is an API in iOS, OS X and Firefox for this information, when the hardware supports it. See this question for a detailed answer: [How to access accelerometer/gyroscope data from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378435/how-to-access-accelerometer-gyroscope-data-from-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The computer would have to have some kind of tilt sensor/ gyro built in with an accessible API.  The mac book pro does have such a device. PCs won't usually as monitors are not part of the PC itself and I am guessing it is the tilt of the monitor you are interested in?

The tilt sensor in a macbook pro is for the laptop rather than the screen angle so again if the laptop screen is fully open or nearly closed this would not be possible to tell.