# how to get acceleration at DeviceMotionEvent

Tags: javascript, html, accelerometer, dart

Using Dart, I'm trying to access accelerometer on an HTML page.
With gyro there is no issue, the documentation clearly states the DeviceOrientationEvent has alpha, beta and gamma properties and it works fine.

But with DeviceMotionEvent, how do I access acceleration? In the documentation:
http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/DeviceMotionEvent.html
you can read: "It provides information about the rate of rotation, as well as acceleration along all three axes.". However, the list of properties doesn't say so, neither the auto complete, nor untyped "hacking" attempts to read 'accelerationIncludingGravity'.

Can I get some hints please?

Thanks!

Comment: I added a bug report at http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=8345

Feel free to star it for immediate updates.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4378439/1318946

Answer (score 0):

The acceleration and accelerationIncludingGravity properties of [DeviceMotionEvent](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/DeviceMotionEvent.html) can now be used, providing access to the x, y, z properties of [DeviceAcceleration](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/DeviceAcceleration.html):

```
window.onDeviceMotion.listen((DeviceMotionEvent e) {
  print(e.acceleration.x);
  print(e.acceleration.y);
  print(e.acceleration.z);
  print(e.accelerationIncludingGravity.x);
});
```

According to [Issue 9092](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=9092), initDeviceMotionEvent is the only thing lacking.