# Trigger programmatically a devicemotion event in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to test hardware support for the `acceleration` property of a `devicemotion` HTMLEvent on mobile devices. As apparently those without a gyroscope only support `accelerationIncludingGravity`.

My first idea is to let the `window` object listen to `devicemotion` and retrieve the information, then remove the listener and add it again with a different handler. But I wonder if there's a more elegant way to test for this.

Comment: This may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378435/how-to-access-accelerometer-gyroscope-data-from-javascript

Comment: @SarathMohan In the first answer of your link, in the `else if` how does he know that the device supports `acceleration`? Not all devices have a gyroscope.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this plugin will help you to work with device motion via JavaScript.
[Accelerometer](http://www.albertosarullo.com/blog/javascript-accelerometer-demo-source)

For a demo you can check this link from mobile.

[**Demo Link**](http://www.albertosarullo.com/demos/accelerometer/)

Comment: The link to the API could not be found?

Comment: Apple had removed that discussion. :| For some details about how to use this may be this answer will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26216960/1310540