# Fix html element regardless device orientation and motion

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, orientation

I have an html element and want to keep it vertically oriented regardless mobile device rotation.
For example:

[image: vertical]
[image: angel]
[image: horizontal]

How can I do it?
Thanks!

Comment: I think this is with regular HTML and JS not possible. But you can use `cordova` that extends the regular browser  functionality. There are cordova plugins that let you read out the orientation of your device: http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/screenorientation

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about current browser support, but you could use accelerometer: [How to access accelerometer/gyroscope data from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378435/how-to-access-accelerometer-gyroscope-data-from-javascript)

Here's a demo too:
http://www.albertosarullo.com/demos/accelerometer/

Please also note that auto screen orientation on your device may cause unexpected behaviour.