# struggling with code to use phones hardware to detect a sudden stop.

Tags: vue.js, gyroscope

i am making an app with vue.js but i want to make one of the features that if you are driving in a car and your cellphones gyroscope or accelerometer detects  sudden stop when you crash it notifies the other 6 users on the app, this is for a project and i am stuck with this issue

the problem is that i do not know what coding to use for using the cellphones gyroscope or accelerometer (whichever one is best) and need some expert help

i have no knowledge of how to do this and i am a complete amateur in this department, any advice or links will help

this app will be for personal use and a college project

Thanks, much appreciated

Comment: Hi. Can you provide some more technical details? Is it a website you open on a phone or do you use a packaging framework like ionic or cordova?

Comment: also see this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378435/how-to-access-accelerometer-gyroscope-data-from-javascript

Comment: sorry for being unclear. I am using vue.js to make the front end and using cordova to use on android phone. and want to use the phone's gps/location to detect if phone has a sudden stop

Comment: Just out of curiosity - are you going to crash your car to test your application?

Comment: No. I am going to throw my phone off the third floor on some matresses. But please refrain from questions that has nothing to do with the problem