# Streaming Real Time Gyroscope of Phones(Android/IOS) to a Website Application on laptop

Tags: javascript, php, html, web, gyroscope

Hi im making a website and want to stream the gyroscope sensors that are in phones(android or iOS) to my website in real time. I have looked at this site https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1386358 however I am not sure on how to get this method to work as I've never used wolfram language. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Rather than ask the 'open ended' and broad question of 'how do I do this', you ought to try to put together a minimal example and ask a specific question related to where you are getting stuck/confused. 
Re: ios sensors - these may help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation OR https://dzone.com/articles/how-use-gyroscope-your-iphone

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be better off with a codesandbox while you try to figure things out. I used one while trying to figure out some ThreeJS stuff, tapping in to the device gyroscope with the Device Orientation API.

You can user webrtc to create a peer to peer connection if you want to read the data on your laptop.

**Here is another post on the topic:**

[How to access accelerometer/gyroscope data from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378435/how-to-access-accelerometer-gyroscope-data-from-javascript)

**Here is some sample code from that post:**

```
window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", handleOrientation, true);
```

The event handler function can look something like this:

```
function handleOrientation(event) {
  var absolute = event.absolute;
  var alpha    = event.alpha;
  var beta     = event.beta;
  var gamma    = event.gamma;
  // Do stuff with the new orientation data
}
```